# Selenium xpath selector based on the element text

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

What would a Selenium xpath selector be for the following HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li>First</li>
   <li>Second</li>
   <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

I need to make Selenium IDE locate the second item on the list based on the element text. I thought `//li='Second'` would do the trick, but apparently it does not.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
ul/li[contains(text(), "Second")]
```

and better still

```
ul/li[text() = 'Second']
```

Comment: Thank you. I am confused though why li[text()="Second"] does not work?

Comment: You know what - it does. Thank you again

Answer (score 7):

```
By.xpath( "//li[contains(text(), 'Second')]" )
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get by text

```
[.= 'Second']
```

or

```
[text() = 'Second']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use like this:

```
//li[. = "Second"]
```

OR

```
//li[contains(., "Second")]
```

Here, `contains` mean that you can match the partial text, so below one is also correct:

```
//li[contains(., "Seco")]
```