# access unordered list selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<ul class="abc">

<li style="width:65px;">


<a href="event.do"onclick="JavaScript";>create new</a>

</li>

<li style="width:70px;">


<a href="event.do"onclick="JavaScript";>home</a>

</li>

</ul>
```

can any one help me with sample selenium web driver sample code to access the create new/home link

Comment: Welcome to SO. Read through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad. Please refer [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example) for implementation.
Here is the selector and find element mechanism you should be using to locate the element. Let me know if you still need help.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[.='create new']")).click();
```

This is text based xpath search. More examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329436/selenium-xpath-selector-based-on-the-element-text)