# Selenium IDE select random name (link)

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-ide

This week were learning Selenium IDE and our teacher wants us to do different tasks with Selenium on a site called konstnarshuset (will have link down below).

He wants us with Selenium IDE to select a random name (link)

http://www.konstnarshuset.org/showroom/konstnarer/

You can see for yourself if you press the link alot of names will pop up in a line and he wants us to make Selenium pick a random name.

I´ve googled around alot but cannot seem to find the answer, very grateful if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

by using xpath u can do this

eg:  a//font[text() = 'random name here']

follow below ink

[Selenium xpath selector based on the element text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329436/selenium-xpath-selector-based-on-the-element-text)

Comment: Thanks Kiran! Will try this :D