# How to select an item in Selenium from the list?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

There is a list item (li), you need to click on it. But for that to cling - it is unclear.

I and for id has tried, and for xpath, and for the text in link - not goes.

```
<li id="l_pr" class=""><a href="https://vk.com/32444224224" onclick="return nav.go(this, event, {noback: true, params: {_ref: 'left_nav'}});" class="left_row">
    <span class="left_fixer">
      <span class="left_count_wrap fl_r left_void"><span class="inl_bl left_count_sign">0</span></span>
      <span class="left_icon fl_l"></span>
      <span class="left_label inl_bl">My page</span>
    </span>
  </a>
  <div class="left_settings" onclick="menuSettings(0)">
  <div class="left_settings_inner"></div>
</div>
</li>
```

I expect to click the My page link

Comment: Please post the code you tried using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium xpath selector based on the element text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329436/selenium-xpath-selector-based-on-the-element-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `click()` the link with text as **My page** as the element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `XPATH` A:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='My page']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[id$='_pr']>a[href^='http'] span.left_label"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH` B :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@id,'_pr')]/a[starts-with(@href,'http')]//span[text()='My page']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there is any existence of iframe in which case you will have to switch to the frame before clicking on the element. if there is no iframe, then clicking on this element seems straight forward.
try this xpath,

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(.,'My page')]/parent::a").click()
```